# Save value of the variables in file xcode ios

Tags: ios, xcode, saving-data

I have an example of saving date of taxtfield

```
- (NSString *) getFilePath {
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saved.plist"];
}

 -(void) saveData {
    NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[myTextField text],nil];
    [value writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

but how I can save value of the variables in file?

```
NSInteger = record1, record2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSInteger` is not an Objective-C type, but you can convert it to `NSNumber` to store it in an array (or dictionary):

```
NSInteger record1 = 17, record2 = 23;
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:record1];
NSNumber *number2 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:record2];
```

Starting with Xcode 4.4, you can also use the "Boxed Expression" syntax:

```
NSNumber *number1 = @(record1);
```

Now you can put the numbers into an array:

```
NSArray *arrayToSave = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:number1, number2, nil];
[arrayToSave writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

You should also consider using a dictionary instead of an array to store the various values, for example (using boxed expressions again):

```
NSDictionary *dictToSave = @{
    @"value1" : number1,
    @"value2" : number2,
    @"textField" : [myTextField text]
};
[dictToSave writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you don't want to write to a specific file, check the `NSUserDefaults` class with the methods `– setInteger:forKey:` and `– integerForKey:` to store and retrieve integer values.